# How to bind async data to lazy load slick carousel in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to integrate slick carousel in my Angular 8 application. I tried to lazy load script similarly like this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slick-carousel?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts .But Carousel is not rendered for *async* data.

The data inside the slick carousel container are dynamic which is retrived from an API call.

```
<div class="screenshots-carousel slick-container">
    <img [src]="image" *ngFor="let image of screenshots">
</div>
```

The screenshot is an async variable

```
this.service.getdata(url).subscribe((response) => {
     this.screenshots = response
}
```

when i click on the navigation link and land in the page the carousel is not rendered but when i refresh the page, i am getting the expected output.

Comment: Are you calling the service after the carousel lazy loaded?. can you try setTimeout with 2000 seconds?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I added *setTimeout* and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right way but here is the solution;

```
<div class="screenshots-carousel slick-container">
    <img [src]="image" *ngFor="let image of screenshots">
</div>
```

in the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'; 

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: './your.view.html'
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { 


  constructor(private service: YourService) { 
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detectDivChanges(); 
  }

  detectDivChanges() {
    const div = document.querySelector('.slick-container');
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutation) => {
      this.homepageCardSlider();
      observer.disconnect();   // just run first change then dont listen div changes.
    });
    observer.observe(div, config);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit (){
   this.service.getdata(url).subscribe((response) => {
     this.screenshots = response });
}

homepageCardSlider() {
  if ($('.slick-container').length) {
      $('.slick-container').slick({
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: false,
          dots: true,
          centerMode: true,
      });
  }

}

}
```

In this way, when the data is added to the div (http response) , you can call the slick method and render slider with the current data.